# refresh host file in firefox without closing

Tags: firefox, hosts

I am using ubuntu and firefox, i have a dev server and production server.

when i develop i use my dev and change my host file:

```
cat /etc/hosts
10.1.1.1 website.com
```

then, firefox uses my dev server

```
cat /etc/hosts
#10.1.1.1 website.com
```

now, my firefox uses the production server.

the problem is when i change from 1 to the other, i have to close firefox. i tried the "offline" and "online" mode and it does not work

is there a way to do this without closing firefox?

Comment: Please also try a Ctrl+F5 refresh. This does a new host name lookup in addition to fetching the page contents afresh.

Comment: I did, but not work, I also tried CTRL+ENTER on the url, nothing

Comment: It seems to be working. You could also try an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=dns&appver=&platform=). (Also, a quick way to restart Firefox is [Shift + F2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI), and enter **restart**).

Comment: didn't work and i dont want to restart, i have always 20 firefox window opened.